# actor scheduler on multiple servers

Tags: playframework, actor, playframework-2.2

We use actor scheduler in our project which is deployed on multiple servers with NGINX.However, the scheduler is started on multiple servers. is there a way to start the scheduler only on one server and when this server gets down, it will start the scheduler on another active server?

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be using [Akka Cluster](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/cluster.html) and specifically [Akka Cluster Singleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-singleton.html), but you have to deal with common cluster problems, like cluster partitions